# Median Moving Range (MMR) charts for weekly reports

Tags: process-improvement, process-engineering

I'm considering creating a Median Moving Range (MMR) chart in order to analyze weekly data and flag extreme values. Can this work? I'm having trouble finding information about MMR charts online so I also welcome any links that could be helpful. Thanks!

Edit: Maybe I should add some clarification. I just learned what a MMR chart is and I'm trying to make sure that adding it to a weekly report is something that could work. My concern is that it might not work for such a small sequence of data.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

A Median Moving Range (MMR) chart can be used to analyze weekly data and flag extreme values.

Collect weekly data for the variable you are interested in analyzing and then calculate the median and moving range for each week.

You can then plot the data on an MMR chart. The median should be plotted on the y-axis and the moving range on the x-axis. Any points that fall outside the control limits on the MMR chart are considered to be extreme values.